# PHP comparison of values inserted from Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I send values from php to script

```
<img src=\"images/add.jpg\" onclick='add_program_user(".$value['id_program'].",".$value['min_age'].",".$value['max_age'].")' onmouseover=\"this.style.cursor='pointer'\" />
```

The script is:

```
function add_program_user(id_program){
    var str="./add_program_user.php?p1="+id_program+"&p2="+min_age+"&p3="+max_age;
    window.location=str;    
}
```

What I would like to do is check in add_program_user.php if the user has the correct age range. My not working code is:

```
$query = "SELECT age FROM user WHERE user.mail = '".$_SESSION['logged_user_mail']."'";
    $res = @mysqli_query($con,$select_query) or die('Error, query1 failed');
    $num_res = mysqli_num_rows($res);
    if($age< min_age || $age> max_age){
        echo '<html><meta charset="UTF-8"><script language="javascript">alert("Wrong age range."); document.location="user_programs.php";</script></html>';
    }
```

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `add_program_user` takes only one parameter in your function definition, while passed three in `onclick` event. Place `console.log(str);` in second line of `add_program_user(id_program)` and post output.

Comment: Okay, first in your JS, you need to correct the line `var str="./add_program_user.php?p1="+id_program+"&p2="+min_age+"&p3"+max_age;`... there's a `=` missing after p3. Second, the `if` part in your add_program_user.php script doesn't make any sense. There are no variables (`age` instead of `$age`)... Where is `$age` defined? And do you need to compare it against the values you get from p2 and p3? Also your JS function only takes 1 parameter, you're passing 3 in your onclick part

Comment: @PatrickManser I thought that I was getting age value from the "SELECT age...". Also, I will edit the mistake in Js. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to suggest some changes to the image section. This just simply makes it easier to read (IMO).
What I have done is to just wrap the array values in curly braces (`{}`) which means that you don't have to concatenate the string with the full stop, which I find easier to read. Note that it is only available when using the double quotes `"`.
So what that means is `add_program_user(".$value['id_program'].","` becomes `add_program_user({$value['id_program']},`

```
echo "<img src=\"images/add.jpg\" onclick=\"add_program_user({$value['id_program']}, {$value['min_age']}, {$value['max_age']})\" onmouseover=\"this.style.cursor='pointer'\" />";
```

My second note would be regarding your JavaScript function. As Patrick Manser said in the comments, you were only passing one argument to the function, but trying to get 3 from it. This is easily rectified by changing the function to the following.

```
function add_program_user(id_program, min_age, max_age) {
    var str = "./add_program_user.php?p1=" + id_program + "&p2=" + min_age + "&p3=" + max_age;
    window.location = str;
}
```

Finally, you didn't use the `$` for the variable names (i.e. `$min_age` in the if statement).
So, I propose the following edits to the PHP script.
I'd also suggest using [prepared queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) in your future queries.

```
<?php
// store the get variables
$id_program = $_GET["p1"];
$min_age    = $_GET["p2"];
$max_age    = $_GET["p3"];

$query = "SELECT age FROM user WHERE user.mail = '{$_SESSION['logged_user_mail']}'";
$res = @mysqli_query($con, $query) or die('Error, query1 failed');
$num_res = mysqli_num_rows($res);

// ensure only one user is selected
if ($num_res == 1)
{
    $age = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC); // store the data
    // check the age range
    if ($age < $min_age || $age > $max_age)
        echo '<html><meta charset="UTF-8"><script language="javascript">alert("Wrong age range."); document.location="user_programs.php";</script></html>';
}
?>
```